# Удалить из списка значения, которых нет в другом списке

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<MyClass>() {
                new MyClass {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("C0AFA906-40D3-4FAA-B7D2-000B6C17CA93"),
                    str = "qwer"
                },
                new MyClass {
                      Id = Guid.Parse("D4AB9FBF-E6F2-4236-A0BE-000C9C55F6D9"),
                    str = "asd"
                },
                  new MyClass {
                      Id = Guid.Parse("АB9C258F-58F4-4F96-8B15-000E38BD55CC"),
                    str = "zxc"
                }
            };

            var list2 = new List<MyClass>() {
                new MyClass {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("C0AFA906-40D3-4FAA-B7D2-000B6C17CA93"),
                    str = "qwer"
                },
                new MyClass {
                      Id = Guid.Parse("D4AB9FBF-E6F2-4236-A0BE-000C9C55F6D9"),
                    str = "asd"
                }
            };

            var list3 = new List<MyClass>();
            foreach (var item1 in list1)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in list2)
                {
                    if (item1.Id == item2.Id)
                        list3.Add(item1);
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in list3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Результат: Id={item.Id}, str={item.str}");
                //Результат две строки: Id=C0AFA906-40D3-4FAA-B7D2-000B6C17CA93, str=qwer; 
                //                      Id =D4AB9FBF-E6F2-4236-A0BE-000C9C55F6D9, str=asd

            }
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string str { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы считаете записи равными по совпадению объектов или по равенству полей?

Comment: добавь пример с данными

Comment: Равные записи те у которых Guid Id одинаковые

Comment: Помоему никакой не дубликат, с тем вопросом ничего общего

Comment: @Alex: А чем вам не подходит там первый ответ? Ну разве что в конце `.ToList()`.

Comment: Мне нужно что то типа: list1.AddRange().list1.Remove().Where(x => x.Id != list2.Id)

Comment: Надеюсь вопрос ясен

Comment: @Alex, абсолютный дубликат, тебе нужно использовать перегрузку _Intersect_ в которой вторым параметром передается _IEqualityComparer_ в котором ты будешь определять равны элементы или нет

Comment: Да не нужно мне это! Мне простой linq запрос нужно, сравнивать буду только по Id, заачем мне Comparer???

Comment: _Мне нужно что то типа_, _Надеюсь вопрос ясен_ - нет теперь не ясен. Добавь в вопрос пример входных и выходных данных, иначе непонятно что ты хочешь получить на выходе. Для редактирования вопроса используй кнопку [edit]

Comment: foreach (var l1 in list1)
            {
                foreach (var l2 in list2)
                {
                    if (l1.Id != l2.Id)
                        list1.Remove(l1);
                }
            }

Comment: Так будет понятнее?

Comment: Нет. Во-первых, добавь дополнения непосредственно в вопрос. Во-вторых, добавь пример с входными и выходными данными. Иначе непонятно какой результат ты ожидаешь получить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57389/discussion-between-alex-and-grundy).

Comment: Добавил, надеюсь теперь понятнее

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы удалить все элементы подходящие под условие можно использовать метод [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdka673a(v=vs.100).aspx)

Далее в предикате нужно проверить условие, что проверяемого элемента нет во втором списке, для этого можно использовать метод [Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
list1.RemoveAll(el=> !list2.Exists(el2=>el2.Id == el.Id))
```

Либо можно использовать метод [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var list3 = list1.Intersect(list2, new CompareByGuid());
```

Где класс CompareByGuid может иметь следующую реализацию:

```
class CompareByGuid : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        //Check whether properties are equal.
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass a)
    {
        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return x.Id.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```